# Where does $2\sqrt{d-1}$ come from in Ramanujan graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, expander-graphs

Ramanujan graphs are the best spectral expanders: $\lambda_2 \le 2\sqrt{d-1}$. I'm looking for some intuition for this value $2\sqrt{d-1}$.

Friedman showed that every random $d$-regular graph achieves $\lambda_2 = 2\sqrt{d-1}+\epsilon$ and Alon-Boppana shows that every sufficiently large $d$-regular graph must have $\lambda_2 \ge 2\sqrt{d-1} - o(1)$. Unfortunately both these results seem quite involved. Is there an easy way to see that the answer should be around $2\sqrt{d-1}$, or at very least $\Theta(\sqrt{d})$? Intuition for either direction would be appreciated.

Comment: this might be useful too https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/cs225/fall16/interlacing-cs225.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, see [this paper by Ram Murty.](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/ramanujan.pdf) The basic point is that the sum of squares of the eigenvalues is the trace of the square of the adjacency matrix, which is equal to $d n.$

Comment: Thanks, this is most of what I was looking for. Is there any intuition for the constant $2$ in front though?

Comment: @XiaoyuHe Extend the argument slightly: suppose your graph has not short cycles, in particular, no 4-cycles. Then, the only paths of length 4 returning to the base point $a$ are $a-b-c-b-a$ and $a-b-a-c-a.$ There are roughly $2k^2$, so the sum of the fourth powers of the eigenvalues is $ 2 k^2 n.$ I think this already gives you the $2.$

Comment: That gives you $2^{1/4} \sqrt{k} \approx 1.19 \sqrt{k}$. There are roughly $5 k^3$ walks of length $6$ (assuming no $4$ or $6$ cycles), giving $5^{1/6} \sqrt{k}  \approx 1.30 \sqrt{k}$. To see the $\sqrt{2}$ you need to look at walks of length $2r$ and send $r \to \infty$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Yes, you are absolutely correct - that was a midnight thought which was not quite thought out.

Answer (score 8):

If you take an infinite regular tree of degree $d$ and fix one vertex $v$, then the number of closed walks of length $2k$ (there are none of odd length) starting at $v$ grows like $4^k(d-1)^k$ as $k\to\infty$.  To see this heuristically, note that you have to move towards $v$ half the time and away from $v$ half the time.  There are $2^{2k}$ choices for which steps you move away from $v$ and for each such step there are $d-1$ choices for which branch to take.   As David says, this is related to the question because Ramanujan graphs are locally tree-like.

Answer (score 6):

Heuristically, an expander $G$ looks locally like the $d$-regular tree $T$. Let $r$ be a positive real number and let $f_x$ be the function on the vertices of $T$ given by $f_x(y) = r^{d(x,y)}$. We have $|f_x|^2 = 1+d \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (d-1)^n r^{2n}$; this sum is convergent as long as $r < 1/\sqrt{d-1}$. Writing $A$ for the adjacency matrix, we have 
$$A f_x = (r^{-1}+(d-1) r) f_x + (r-r^{-1}) \delta_x$$
where $\delta_x$ is the $\delta$ function at $x$. As $r \to \tfrac{1^{-}}{\sqrt{d-1}}$, the norm of $f_x$ grows while $(r-r^{-1}) \delta_x$ remains bounded. So, intuitively, at $r=1/\sqrt{d-1}$, the function $f$ acts like an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\sqrt{d-1} + (d-1)/\sqrt{d-1} = 2 \sqrt{d-1}$.

In an expander, $G$ still locally looks like $T$. Take two vertices $x$ and $y$ that are very far apart and consider $f_x - f_y$. This is orthogonal to $1$, so $\tfrac{\langle f_x-f_y, \ A (f_x - f_y) \rangle}{\langle f_x-f_y, \ f_x-f_y \rangle}$ is a lower bound for $\lambda_2$. Assuming we take $r < 1/\sqrt{d-1}$, the overlap between $f_x$ and $f_y$ will be negligible and the analysis will be dominated by the behavior near $x$ and $y$, which will look like the case of $T$.

For a rigorous proof of Alon-Boppana along vaguely these lines, see [Theorem 5 here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dce27/Eigenvalues2.pdf). I'm not claiming the arguments are very close, but they start with two points that are far apart and use them to build a function $g$ with $\langle g,\ 1 \rangle=0$ and $\tfrac{\langle g, A^{2k} g \rangle}{\langle g,g \rangle}$ large by using that $G$ locally looks like $T$.